# How to output JSON data in Azure Data Facory

Tags: json, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Hi I am working in azure data factory and azure c# function. I am trying to send some data as json from azure data factory to c# azure function. In add dynamic content I want to send some of the parameters as JSON. For example, we have parameters UserID and ID. Below is my sample model of c# azure function

```
public class MyModel
{
public string UserID {get;set;}
public string ID {get;set;}
}
```

My ADF dynamic content is

```
@pipeline().parameters.UserId
```

But in the above dynamic content I would like to send two parameters  @pipeline().parameters.UserId and  @pipeline().parameters.ID as JSON to my azure function. Can someone help me to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) in your pipeline, select 'POST' as method. Then in 'Body', use dynamic content as

```
{
  "UserID": "@{pipeline().parameters.UserId}",
  "ID": "@{pipeline().parameters.ID}"
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did as above but which resulted in  "{\n  \"UserID\": \"@pipeline().parameters.UserId\",\n  \"ID\": \"@pipeline().parameters.ID\"\n}"
}

Comment: That's fine. JSON should be parsed fine with \n (new line), escape qoute (\") or indentation. Do you see any error when you run the pipeline?

Comment: Yeah but real values should be replaced right instead of @pipeline().parameters.UserId

Comment: Can you try like "@{pipeline().parameters.UserId}"? (interpolation)

Comment: This resulted in "body": "{ \"UserID\": \"Niranjan.Godbole@mydomain.com\", \"ID\": \"roughid\"}\n"

Comment: That means now it's fine :). Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes I am able to get dynamic content. But how can I get rid of this slashes?

Comment: The 'body' is a string field in Data Factory. So those are escaped. But do you see any problem? The function should parse the JSON fine as per my experience.

Comment: Yes Krish I am unable to send it to above model of azure function